# Best Way to Backup Multiple FTP and DBs?

Tags: hosting, vps, web-hosting

I have a VPS with http://knownhost.com which has been a great company but I plan to switch to http://wiredtree.com soon. I was wondering what is the best and safest way to backup 5 complete websites every 24 hrs so there is little room for error? I would like to backup FTP and the Databased and move them somewhere else if possible, just looking for a solution just incase something happens to my host where i might lose access to the websites + backups

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a one-time thing, some light scripting and use of `tar` and `scp` will probably do you just fine.

For a longer-term solution, I've made heavy use of Bacula. The support for regular backups across any number of systems is quite nice for ongoing work.

No matter what you do, the question of whether it is working needs to be tested. Bring a new machine online and try restoring to it from the backups you create. If you can't, adjust and try again.